# Spring issue with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, autowired

This is a controller which `@autowire TestRunner testRunner`. I think spring creates beans with singletone scope so testRunner will be shared among all threads.
This `testRunner` usese `setTestRunner` method to set some variables which are class level.

Will this approach create problem in multithreading ?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HomeController {

@Autowire
TestRunner testRunner;  

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void addCustomerPage(User user) {

        A a = new A();
        a.set(user.get) ....
        B b = new B();
        b.set(user.get) ....
        C c = new C();
        c.set(user.get) ....

        testRunner.setTestRunner(a, b, c); 
        Thread t = new Thread(testRunner);
        t.start();
    }

}
```

This is TestRunner class.

```
@Component
public class TestRunner implements Runnable{

    private A a;
    private B b;
    private C c;

    public void setTestRunner(A a, B b, C c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        //  use a,b,c.

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it would,

Your test runner class is singleton, so it lives in the application scope thereby the same instance is shared among the whole application.

However you use it in a stateful manner, setting values to it depending on what you recieve in your request.

Either make your TestRunner class scope as prototype or don't autowire at all and create a new testrunner instance

```
@Scope(value = "prototype")
```

Comment: I tried with new testRunner instance but then I won't be able to use spring autowiring feature in testRunner so I had to autowire TestRunner class. You mentioned about prototype scope which could be one option but could you please tell me if it will have any drawbacks in the application?

Comment: The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific bean is made. It is thereby similar to creating by new Instance(). The drawbacks are fully dependant on your application but there will be none in the example you provide. More on the topic : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/html/ch03s05.html

Comment: Thx. I got your point. One last question is adding @Scope("prototype") above TestRunner class will do the job, right?

Comment: So I added prototype scope for TestRunner & deployed the code. I just printed testRunner before testRunner.setTestRunner(a, b, c).
It should print different hashcode every time (considering that it will create a new object every time it gets called) I hit '.../welcome.htm' but it prints the same hashcode. Any idea why?

Comment: Your controller is singleton, therefore anything inside it is created only once. Hence everytime it gives reference to the testRunner class it is the same instance it created at the beginning. Instead of a class variable you need a local variable and create a new testRunner instance in addCustomerPage method if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Prototype only ensures that a seperate instance would be created should you give reference to a testRunner instance in a different class, otherwise a class variable behaves as always, autowired or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64680/discussion-between-user1298426-and-pumpkin).